# Power Apps, Shrinking the layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a power app created by canvas in a landscape format.
I've tried scaling it down using File->Settings->Display->Size.
However I dont have the option for size.

[image]

I am trying to shrink my fields to fit more in the screen. Is there anyway to shrink these fields in a quick fashion? These tiles are so big.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see height and width controls, you need to turn off the **Scale to fit** feature:

[image]